# Outlook 2007 + Symantec Enterprise Vault: saving copy of email does not maintain the original received date

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, symantec

At my employer we use Outlook 2007 + Symantec Enterprise Vault for archiving. Messages older than 30 days are automatically archived, until 6 months and then they are deleted if not marked with the category "Do Not Purge".

I need to add "Do Not Purge" to my email messages that I want to keep. A few weeks ago it worked fine. If I did this on archived messages, it would tell me it would have to create a copy of the email (I guess the archived items are immutable), but that's no big deal, I would just delete the original and keep the copy; the copy maintained the original received date/time.

Now when the email message is copied, the copy gets the date/time as of when the copy is created, not the original email received date/time. Is there a way to fix this on my client, or is this a server problem? I have no idea why this is occurring and I have about a week left before I start to lose email messages.

Comment: Surely this is something you should take to whoever maintains your Exchange and EV?

Comment: Already done so 2 days ago. No response yet from my latest request for help. (The person I talked do didn't have this problem + asked for a screenshot so he could see what I was talking about.) Our IT staff seems to assume most help questions are of the dumb / easy type and can be delegated to entry-level offshore IT staff.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a straight out problem with Vault - have you tried logging into another PC in your office (hoping Outlook autodiscovers) to assess whether it is a PC or back-end issue? As long as the Vault client is installed on all your PCs (again, I would assume it is) it will sync down fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this problem occurred, but out of desperation I uninstalled GPG4Win, which I had installed a few weeks ago, and the problem is fixed. (I guess their GpgOL plugin for Outlook does something it shouldn't.)